# Weird Admob error

Tags: android, xml, layout, manifest, admob

Weird Admob error. I am still a noob so not sure if there is something seriously wrong with my code.

Admob is not giving my application an error however Admob ads do not appear in the app.

Even stranger is that when viewing main.xml in graphical layout I do see "Ads by Google" where the ads should be viewable. I've installed the app several times now and refreshed however nothing appears on the real device. I am using the updated Admob jar / package to GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.1.jar.

My main.xml is below

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a14e27391701ceb"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and my manifest is:

```
<!-- AdMob Begin Code -->
<meta-data 
    android:value="a14e27391701ceb" 
    android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
<activity android:name="com.admob.android.ads.AdMobActivity"/>
<receiver 
    android:name="com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<meta-data 
    android:value="true" 
    android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS"/>
</application>
<!-- AdMob End Code -->
```

Comment: Did you debug? Was there something tagged _Ads_ in the LogCat log? Sometimes AdMob just doesn't have enough ads to fill the ad.

Comment: There are no errors to debug! It is not crashing at all, just not displaying any ads. No matter how many times I attempted refreshing it. It does indicate it exists when main.xml is viewed in graphical layout - I do see "Ads by Google" where the ads would normally be viewable on a live device however I have tested on two live devices and the same thing. Nothing, not even an error.

Comment: It is possible that AdMob would not have any ad to fill up the banner. can you try using the test Mode which would guarantee test ad?

Comment: @Kazuko You don't need to have errors to debug. AdMob logs its actions by default and they show up tagged as `Ads` in LogCat. It should show you what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView1);
AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
re.setTesting(true);
adview.loadAd(re);

Hope it will helps.

Comment: I believe I may have found out the problem lies with AdMob. Apparently, there's a significant bug in the version AdMob just pushed out LIVE to PRODUCTION on July 19th! The admob jar is only about 50K in size and the .zip itself does not contain the instructions or pdf. See the following URL. groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/…. I personally have already put in approximately 25 hours attempting to resolve the issue.